# MVC Razor HTML Helper syntax: Viewbag in Html.Hidden object parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add a object to my Html.Hidden HTML helper, but I can't get the syntax quite right.

**Syntax 1:**

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenDate", ViewBag.myDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

Results in runtime error and it can't resolve the @Html.Hidden in view.

**Syntax 2:**

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenDate", new { String = ViewBag.myDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")})
```

Sets the value="{ String = 16.04.2012 }"

I would like to get the value to only "16.04.2012", but no success after several syntax tweaks

Comment: what's the method declaration look like?

Comment: HtmlHelper.Hidden(string name, object value)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try casting the return value to `object`:

```
@Html.Hidden("hiddenDate", (object)ViewBag.myDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I should have thought on this as my first syntax gave me syntax error, but I just didn't cross my mind. Thank you again!